# Position of Indices in Einstein's Summation Convention

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Would there be a difference between the following tensor quantities?

$$ {A_\gamma}^\mu {B_\mu}^\rho $$ and $$ {A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $$

Would both of these expressions give the same result as follows
$$ {X_\gamma}^\rho = {A_\gamma}^\mu {B_\mu}^\rho = {A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho? $$

As the positions of the indices in Einstein's summation convention make a difference, I believe that the two expressions are not equivalent. The first equation $ {X_\gamma}^\rho = {A_\gamma}^\mu {B_\mu}^\rho $ makes sense to me as the positions of the indices $\gamma$ and $\rho$ are clear in the resultant quantity ${X_\gamma}^\rho$ but I am unsure of the second equation. Would $ {X_\gamma}^\rho = {A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $?

Answer (score 9):

> Would there be a difference between the following tensor quantities?

Yes. Your equation is false. The *l.h.s.* contracts the second index, and the *r.h.s.* one contracts the first one (even if you are using the same letter for the index). Unless your tensors have some sort of symmetry, these expressions do not agree.

Comment: It would be helpful to add that if you make an analogy with matrix multiplication, it is like comparing $\mathbf{AB}$ and $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: Would ${X_\gamma}^\rho = {A_\gamma}^\mu {B_\mu}^\rho$ and $Y_{\hspace{6pt}\gamma}^{\hspace{3pt}\rho} = {A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $ where $\rho$ and $\gamma$ are in the second index positions for $Y_{\hspace{6pt}\gamma}^{\hspace{3pt}\rho}$?

Comment: @Charles what are you trying to write? note that $A^\mu{}_\nu$ can be written as `A^\mu{}_\nu` and $A_\mu{}^\nu$ can we written as `A_\mu{}^\nu`

Comment: Would ${A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho$ contract over the first index to give a tensor $Y_{\hspace{6pt}\gamma}^{\hspace{3pt}\rho} $ where $\rho$ and $\gamma$ are in the second index positions? Or would having two indices in the same positions be an invalid notation?

Comment: In $I^\rho_\gamma$ the indices are not in the same position: one is an upstairs and one is downstairs. If you are worried about the *horizontal* position of the index, I fear that there is little consensus: for some people it is right to write $I^\mu{}_\nu$ simply as $I^\mu_\nu$, ignoring the horizontal position. For some other people such a notation can only be used if $I$ is symmetric. And for some people, you cannot write $I^\mu{}_\nu$ as $I^\mu_\nu$. In the end, as long as you understand what you are writing, and are consistent and clear with the notation, you can write whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my point. I was referring to the horizontal indices. How should I view the difference between ${A_\gamma}^\mu {B_\mu}^\rho$ and ${A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $ to be since ${A_\gamma}^\mu$ and ${A^\mu}_\gamma$ only differ by the horizontal positions of the indices?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then the horizontal positioning is irrelevant: both expressions agree. If $A$ is not symmetric, then you should not move the indices horizontally. If you are new to index notation, you should not never move the indices horizontally. Once you get used to the notation, you'll see that it is convenient to relax the notation to allow some flexibility. But, for now, keep the indices where they are.

Comment: How would you write the resultant tensor with its indices for ${A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $? Would $Y_{\hspace{5pt}\gamma}^{\hspace{3pt}\rho} = {A^\mu}_\gamma {B_\mu}^\rho $ be correct if we are strict on the horizontal positioning of indices?

Comment: I would personally write either $Y_\gamma{}^\rho$ or $Y^\rho{}_\gamma$ (but not both! choose one and stick to it). I would **not** write it as $Y{}^\rho_\gamma$.

Comment: That makes sense. No issues will arise if the index notations are consistent. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Exactly: as long as you state very clearly what convention you use and keep it consistently, you can write whatever you want. Some people would even write $A_\mu B_\mu$ for index contractions, both downstairs! I don't like that convention, but it exists. In the end, use the convention that works best for you. As long as you understand what you are doing, and as long as you are capable of communicating with the rest of people, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ such that $\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^\mu \; \eta_{\mu\nu} \; \Delta x^\nu$. Denote the inverse metric as $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ so that $\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\nu \rho} = \delta_{\mu}^{\,\,\rho}$.

Start with tensor with only index up, like
$$
A^{\gamma\mu} \qquad \qquad \text{and} \qquad \qquad B^{\mu \rho}
$$
then *define* the lower-index version of these tensors by contracting with the metric $\eta^{\mu\nu}$:
$$
A_{\gamma}^{\;\,\mu} := \eta_{\gamma \alpha} A^{\alpha \mu}; \qquad \qquad
A_{\,\;\mu}^{\gamma} := \eta_{\mu \alpha} A^{ \gamma\alpha}
$$
and so on.

You see that for instance
$$
X_{\gamma}^{\;\;\rho} = A_{\gamma}^{\;\;\mu} B^{\;\;\rho}_{\mu} \equiv 
\eta_{\gamma \alpha} \eta_{\mu\beta} A^{\alpha\mu}B^{\beta\rho}
$$
whereas
$$
Y_{\gamma}^{\;\rho} = A_{\;\;\gamma}^{\mu} B^{\;\;\rho}_{\mu} \equiv 
\eta_{\gamma \alpha} \eta_{\mu\beta} A^{\mu\alpha}B^{\beta\rho}
$$
and you see that are, in general, two different tensors, and only if $A$ (in this case) is symmetric they are equal.

But note that calling the first quantity $X_{\gamma}^{\;\;\rho} $ or$ X_{\;\;\gamma}^{\rho} $ is only a matter of definition, they would both be consistent with index conventions.